# Limiting Number of Posts Per Page - Ruby on Rails Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently developing a Ruby on Rails blog. I have my blog posts show up on the main page, however, I would like to list the posts 5 at a time, so that my frontpage doesn't go on forever and my blog will look much cleaner.

Let me know if you can help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need a pagination solution - consider using kaminari or will_paginate ( https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari, https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki )

And if you need an endless page, there is a nice screencast about that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page

Answer (score 1):

For example, if using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) for pagination, you just call paginate method at end of line your query inside controller, for example inside your controller

```
def index
  @blogs = Blog.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

from your view, just simply put:

```
will_paginate @blogs
```

at specify location, to show pagination.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this, but I am always returning a undefined method 'paginate' error. I checked to see if willpaginate was installed in my bundle and it appears to be on there. Am I missing some sort of route or something?

Comment: could you puts your code that calling paginate method ? from your rails console please type  "ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate" without("), output should be true

Comment: @blah = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/will_paginate/browse_thread/thread/cc7ad9391b3b7fd3/d1de899e7cdd0a71?pli=1 try this, sorry for late answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to limit the number of post on the home page . Then you should do like

```
Model.find(:all, :limit => 5, :order=> 'created_at desc')
```

you can remove the order if you don't need it. If you need to make pagination take a look at [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)